# Onclick doesn't work after remove/add class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to understand why this code work only with first onclick:

html:

```
    <div id="TheCarouselPlay">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs pause">
            <i class="fa fa-pause"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
```

js:

```
/* pause & play */
$('#TheCarouselPlay button.pause').click(function () {
    $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
    $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
});
$('#TheCarouselPlay button.play').click(function () {
    $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
    $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W59Me/4/

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with one button click handler, checking the current state based on which class the button currently has:

```
$('#TheCarouselPlay button').click(function () {
    if($(this).hasClass('play')){
      $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
      $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
    } else{
      $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
      $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play'); 
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/gW2pn/

Comment: This should work, because in your code, the div has both the classes, pause and play at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Try using event handlers instead:

```
    /* pause & play */
$('#TheCarouselPlay').on('click', 'button.pause', function () {
    $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
    $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
});
$('#TheCarouselPlay').on('click', 'button.play', function () {
    $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
    $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
});
```

Here is the new fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xe79K/

Answer (score 1):

You have to use on()

```
/* pause & play */
$('#TheCarouselPlay').on('click','button.pause',function () {
    $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-pause').addClass('fa-play');
    $(this).removeClass('pause').addClass('play');
});
$('#TheCarouselPlay').on('click','button.play',function () {
    $('#TheCarouselPlay i').removeClass('fa-play').addClass('fa-pause');
    $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
});
```

Because button.play didn't exist when you defined the click event.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout function will do the trick.
Here is an example:

```
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(this).removeClass('play').addClass('pause');
    }, 100);
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation why the code you provided solves the issue? It would be much better than code-only answer :)